# Error in url rewrite if i remove .html from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am having some issues with url rewriting
I am using this as my code for rewrite in htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /pages.php?id=$1 [L]
```

this was my url

```
studentsassignmenthelp.com/pages.php?id=Marketing-Assignment-Help
```

after using the url rewrite i am getting this

```
studentsassignmenthelp.com/Marketing-Assignment-Help.html
```

but i need it without the html like the below one

```
studentsassignmenthelp.com/Marketing-Assignment-Help
```

if i use the below code to remove the .html than it shows error 500 server...

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /pages.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I saw some example but after using them it shows 404 or 500 error

Comment: For `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /pages.php?id=$1 [L]` rule to execute the request URI needs to contain `.html` in the end. Not as your describing. Also it rewrites a `/home.html` request to `/pages.php?id=home`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !pages.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank You........ i worked for me but please explain it so that in future i will have the same problem

Comment: You are welcome... :), and this may be helpful http://randomtype.ca/blog/the-wordpress-htaccess-file-explained/

Comment: What i should do if i have more pages like
studentsassignmenthelp.com/pages.php?id=Marketing-Assignment-Help 
studentsassignmenthelp.com/profile.php?id=Vivek

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /pages.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

redirectMatch 301 ^(.*).html $1

This is quite usefull to remove any url extension and avoid broken links.